# Do these zeros have real part equal to $0$?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, complex-numbers

I guess this is a known result but I could not find it on the Internet. Consider these equations formed from the reciprocals of the divisors of $n$ raised to a complex number $s=a+ib$ :

$\displaystyle 1$

$\displaystyle 1 + \frac{1}{2^s}=0$

$\displaystyle 1 + \frac{1}{3^s}=0$

$\displaystyle 1 + \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{4^s}=0$

$\displaystyle 1 + \frac{1}{5^s}=0$

$\displaystyle 1 + \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{3^s} + \frac{1}{6^s}=0$

$\displaystyle 1 + \frac{1}{7^s}=0$

$\displaystyle 1 + \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{4^s} + \frac{1}{8^s}=0$

$\displaystyle 1 + \frac{1}{3^s} + \frac{1}{9^s}=0$

$\displaystyle 1 + \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{5^s} + \frac{1}{10^s}=0$

$\displaystyle 1 + \frac{1}{11^s}=0$

$\displaystyle 1 + \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{3^s} + \frac{1}{4^s} + \frac{1}{6^s} + \frac{1}{12^s}=0$

$...$

Is it true that the zeros have real part equal to $0$ ?

[Wolfram Alpha example, sums of reciprocals of divisors of 30](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BFindRoot%5B1%2B1%2F2%5E%28s%29%2B1%2F3%5E%28s%29%2B1%2F5%5E%28s%29%2B1%2F6%5E%28s%29%2B1%2F10%5E%28s%29%2B1%2F15%5E%28s%29%2B1%2F30%5E%28s%29%3D%3D0%2C%7Bs%2C5%2an%2aI%7D%5D%2C+%7Bn%2C+1%2C+30%7D%5D)

This Mathematica program finds some of the zeros up to the number $42$.

```
Clear[nn, s];
Do[
 nn = i;
 Total[1/Divisors[nn]^(s)];
 Print[s /.Table[FindRoot[Total[1/Divisors[nn]^(s)] == 0,
  {s, 5*n*I}], {n, 1, 30}]], {i, 2, 42}]
```

There are cases when the FindRoot command in Mathematica gives solutions that have real part not equal to zero, but these appear to be accompanied with warning messages and I have checked numerically that those solutions are not zeros.

Comment: I don't think so; they look like they just have zeros with very nearly real part zero. The first one, for instance, also has zeros with real parts about 94.5 and 349.8. A variant of this question that I've personally wondered is if $$\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}$$ always has zeros with real part in $(0,1)$ (which numerically appears correct).

Comment: It could be you are right. But by considering a different version where the reciprocals are raised to $(s-1)$ I get real part equal to $1$. That is I entered in Wolfram Alpha: Table[FindRoot[1+1/2^(s-1)+1/3^(s-1)+1/5^(s-1)+1/6^(s-1)+1/10^(s-1)+1/15^(s-1)+1/30^(s-1)==0,{s,5*n*I}], {n, 1, 30}]

Comment: Interesting.. but the period in "1." makes me think that's still approximate. I should also mention you're specifically talking about $\sigma_{-s}(n)$ ([divisor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)) as a function of complex $s$.

Comment: As a *Mathematica* note: `DivisorSigma[-s, nn]` is a simpler expression for the functions you're interested in... (edit: and I only saw @anon's comment just now.)

Comment: Since you're in *Mathematica*: it might be useful for you to peer at contours: `Partition[Table[ContourPlot[{Re[DivisorSigma[-(x + I y), k]] == 0, Im[DivisorSigma[-(x + I y), k]] == 0}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], {k, 2, 41}], 5] // Grid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $s=0$, the property fails hence one can assume without loss of generality that $s\ne0$ and that the integer $n\geqslant2$ is the product of some $p_j^{k_j}$. Define $Z=2i\pi\mathbb Z$ as the set of integer multiples of $2i\pi$.

First assume that $p_j^s\ne1$ for every $j$. Then, the sum you are interested in is
$$
S_n(s)=\prod_j\left(\sum_{t=0}^{k_j}p_j^{-st}\right)=\prod_j\frac{1-p_j^{-s(k_j+1)}}{1-p_j^{-s}}.
$$
The zeros $s$ of $S_n$ solve one of the equations
$$
p_j^{s(k_j+1)}=1.
$$
This happens if and only if $s(k_j+1)\log p_j$ is in $Z$.

On the other hand, $p_j^s=1$ for some $j$ means that $s\log p_j$ is in $Z$. For every such $j$, one should replace the contribution of $p_j$ in $S_n(s)$ by $k_j+1\ne0$.

One is left with the condition that there exists at least one $j$ such that $s\log p_j$ is not in $Z$ and $s(k_j+1)\log p_j$ is in $Z$. That is, there exists $j$ and an integer $\ell$ which is not zero modulo $k_j+1$, such that
$$
s=\frac{2i\pi\ell}{(k_j+1)\log p_j}.
$$
Note that since the $\log p_j$ are linearly independent over the rationals, this can happen for at most one prime number $p_j$ dividing $n$.

In particular the real part of $s$ must be zero.

Comment: Oh duh, just factor $\sigma_{-s}(n)$. I should have thought of that.

Comment: @anon, provided you are the anon who found *zeros with real parts about 94.5 and 349.8*, I am curious to know if you made a mistake, or if I misunderstood what you said, or what.

Comment: I [changed OP's example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BFindRoot%5B1%2B1%2F2^%28s%29%3D%3D0%2C{s%2C5*n*I}%5D%2C+{n%2C+1%2C+30}%5D) to just $1+1/2^s$. Either I misunderstood the code or Alpha screwed up big time.

Comment: @anon, did you write 1/2(s) instead of 1/2^s?

Comment: M.SE keeps mutilating the link, so just type in `Table[FindRoot[1+1/2^(s)==0,{s,5*n*I}],{n,1,30}]` and you should see [this](http://i.imgur.com/SATk5.png) (.png screengrab).